# Travelling within US without my passport

Tags: usa, passports, paperwork, airport-security

I am an international student from San Francisco who is travelling to Belgium to attend a conference. I have an interview scheduled with the Belgian consulate tomorrow in Los Angeles. On my return flight, I won't have any government-issued identification, as I will have to submit my passport for visa processing, and I don't have a government issued driving license.

What form of alternate identification can I produce for airport security so that they can let me through?

Comment: I would say bring everything you have with you, especially any bank cards you might have and any non-government identification such as your university ID.  I would also tell the TSA in San Francisco that you're planning to leave your passport in LA for a visa application and you'll be returning without it.  It might not help, but it might.  Expect to be subjected to extra screening measures on your return; see https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification.

Comment: @zaph why would that matter?

Comment: If he is a US citizen there are several ways to get an official ID. Also one can get an additional passport so one can travel while their passport is unavailable due to obtaining a visa.

Comment: @zaph if OP were a US citizen it would not be necessary to get a visa to attend a conference in Belgium (and it would be unlikely for a US citizen in San Francisco to call him or herself an "international student").  The second passport idea is a good one, and many other countries offer that option.